# is $(-1)^n/n$ continuous for n>1 in the reals?

Tags: calculus

Having a dispute with a very smart person and his claim is that $\left(-1\right)^n/n$ is not continous.  I know that it is not continous at zero; however, the domain that the problem comes from is from 1 to infinity.

the Limit of $\left(-1\right)^n/n$ exist on the restricted domain, am I missing something?

Comment: are you talking about a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=(-1)^x/x$ ??

Comment: I assume you should modify your problem as $\dfrac{e^{(2k+1)i\pi x}}{x}$

Comment: This all depends on how you define $(-1)^p$ for non-integer $p$.

Comment: What is the range? What is $f(3/2)$?

Comment: @Jonathan yes, we only deal with Reals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer, the function is not continuous because the values are distinct.  If $n$ is a positive real, $(-1)^n$ is not well defined if the values are real.  You have $(-1)^1=-1, (-1)^2=1$.  By the intermediate value theorem, if the function were continuous there should be $x$ between $1$ and $2$ with $(-1)^x=0$ but there isn't.  If the values of the function are allowed to be complex, you can  take a particular branch of the logarithm and say $(-1)^n/n=\frac {\exp(i \pi x)}x$ which is nicely continuous for $x$ on the positive real axis.

Answer (score 4):

The integers are a discrete topological space. Every function defined into the real numbers is continuous.  Mr. Millikan has the best solution if you want this function to be a function of a real variable.